# How can I make my button to do something in Fragments,ViewPager

Tags: android, fragment, android-viewpager

First I must say that I'm not good at English and "completely new" to Android Programming.

I want to create an app like Android's home screen which can slide left-right to see the views. On my app, each view will have a button to do something; Now I have accomplished the sliding part by using ViewPager and Fragments. When I run my app, it can smoothly go left-right views but I can't find the solution to make a button in each view to working. How can I do this? Thank you very much for every of your answers. Followings are my code(I modified it from examples over the internet).

This the main fragment class that contains many fragments in it.

```
public class LessonsActivity extends FragmentActivity{
/** maintains the pager adapter */
private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

/*
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setContentView(R.layout.viewpager_layout);
    // initialsie the pager
    this.initialisePaging();
}

/**
 * Initialise the fragments to be paged
 */
private void initialisePaging() {

    List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Lesson_1.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Lesson_2.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Lesson_3.class.getName()));
    fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Lesson_4.class.getName()));
    this.mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(
            super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    //
    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

}
```

}

This below is the fragment class that I used to display the layout.

```
public class Lesson_1 extends Fragment {
/**
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * 
 * @see android.support.v4.app.Fragment#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,
 *      android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)
 */
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
        // We have different layouts, and in one of them this
        // fragment's containing frame doesn't exist. The fragment
        // may still be created from its saved state, but there is
        // no reason to try to create its view hierarchy because it
        // won't be displayed. Note this is not needed -- we could
        // just run the code below, where we would create and return
        // the view hierarchy; it would just never be used.
        return null;
    }
    return (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.lessons1, container,
            false);

}
```

}

And this is my PagerAdapterClass

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private List<Fragment> fragments;
/**
 * @param fm
 * @param fragments
 */
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter#getItem(int)
 */
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter#getCount()
 */
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}
```

}

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your `Fragment`, in the method `onCreateView()` you're returning the view for a specific `Fragment`. This means you can manipulate it. Instead of immediately returning the (inflated) view, put it in a variable and manipulate that variable, like so:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (container == null) {
        ...
        return null;
    }

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.lessons1,
                    container, false);

    // note that we're looking for a button with id="@+id/myButton" in your inflated layout
    // Naturally, this can be any View; it doesn't have to be a button
    Button mButton = (Button) mLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // here you set what you want to do when user clicks your button,
            // e.g. launch a new activity
        }
    });

    // after you've done all your manipulation, return your layout to be shown
    return mLinearLayout;
}
```

Comment: Uh... When I create a new Intent to start a new activity(Contain layout in it), When I run, It show as a dialog box, not the full screen layout. Why?

Comment: Doesn't it need to ba a `View.OnClickListener` and not a `OnClickListener`?