# Android Studio: Moving between fragments and actions inside fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

My project operates around a navigation activity that uses fragments for the individual menu pages. I'd like to be able to open other fragments through clicking a button (as opposed to a navigation menu icon), however I can't figure out how to accomplish this. I've looked at both the following resources (and more), but I don't fully understand them.

[How can I make my button to do something in Fragments,ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838301/how-can-i-make-my-button-to-do-something-in-fragments-viewpager)
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Furthermore, clicking a button would also have to call on code in the main activity that uses the app bar.

If someone can explain to me how to accomplish the desired effect, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a fragment by pressing a button from a fragment the call should go through the current activity.

Create a callback to the activity and call that callback when pressing the button. Then the Activity launches the second fragment when the callback is called.

This way the first fragment does not need to know anything about the second fragment. The Activity deals with the navigation between fragments in the same activity.

I think this is the cleanest and easiest solution.

edit: I'm basically saying the same as the link to the android documentation posted in the question. I think this is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity: Activity = [A], Fragment 1 = [B], and Fragment 2 = [C]

Step 1: Create an interface inside [B] called `IOnInitiate[C]Listener`, and within that interface create a method called `void Initiate[C]();`.

Step 2: Create a private property within [B] of type `IOnInitiate[C]Listener` called `(your-prefix-convention)OnInitiate[C]Listener`.

Step 3: Create a public method within [B] called `public void SetInitiate[C]Listener(Activity activity)`, and cast the `activity` parameter into the private property created in step 2.

Step 4: [A] *must* implement the interface `[B].IOnInitiate[C]Listener` and the method `public void Initiate[C]()`.

Step 5: From [A], whenever you create a new instance of [B], be sure to call the method from step 3 and pass in `this` for the Activity parameter. Otherwise a null exception will occur.

Step 6: Now whenever you need to initiate [C] from [B] simply call the interface method from [B]'s private property. Example:`(prefix)OnInitiate[C]Listener.Initiate[C]();`

This is what mine looks like. I use C# for my development, so your syntax may be different.

```
public class A : Activity, B.IOnInitiateCListener
{
    private void InitiateB()
    {
        B b = new B();
        b.SetInitiateCListener(this);
        b.Show(FragmentManager, "B");
    }

    public void InitiateC()
    {
        C c = new C();
        c.Show(FragmentManager, "C");
    }
}

public class B : Fragment
{
    public interface IOnInitiateCListener
    {
        void InitiateC();
    }

    private IOnInitiateCListener _IOnInitiateCListener;

    public void SetInitiateCListener(Activity activity)
    {
        _IOnInitiateCListener = (IOnInitiateCListener)activity;
    }

    private void InitiateC()
    {
        _IOnInitiateCListener.InitiateC();
    }
}
```